# Display document from Blob column using laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, blob

I am trying to display a document (pdf or image) from a Blob column in Mysql.

Here is my code to upload a pdf or image file.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        Request()->validate([
            'userfile' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            ]);

            $f = $request->file('userfile');
            $att = new \App\Image;
            $att->vno = $request->vno;
            $att->vtype = $request->vtype;
            $att->descrip = $request->docdesc;
            $att->fname = $f->getClientOriginalName();
            $att->imagefile = base64_encode(file_get_contents($f->getRealPath()));
            $att->mime = $f->getMimeType();
            $att->size = $f->getSize();
            $att->save();
            return response()->json(['success'=>$att->id]);
    }
```

To retrieve and show the document i am using following code.

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $doc = DB::table('images')->where('id',$id)->get();
        $tmpdoc = $doc[0]->imagefile;
        return Response::make($tmpdoc, 200, [
            'Content-Type' => $doc[0]->mime,
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$doc[0]->fname.'"'
        ]);
    }
```

But i get a blank page in case of an image file and "Failed to load pdf document" for a pdf document.

---

UPDATE

Manually uploaded an Image and a PDF document to MySQL using WorkBench and this image is  displaying properly. So i think there is some issue in file upload section.

HTML to upload is

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="docdesc" name="docdesc" placeholder="Enter description for document" value="">
  <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="addDoc">Attach</button>
</div>
```

and ajax code

```
$('#addDoc').click(function (e) {
    // Save Image to Table
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('userfile', $('#filename')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        data: fd,
        url: "{{ route('images.store') }}",
        cache:false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#documentForm').trigger("reset");
        },
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing the content size as well and the below header :

```
    return Response::make($tmpdoc, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => $doc[0]->mime,
        'Content-length' => strlen($tmpdoc),
        'Pragma'=>'private',
        'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=0',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$doc[0]->fname.'"'
    ]);
```

Comment: Manually uploaded an Image and a PDF document using workbench and they are being displayed, I think there is some issue in the code to upload document.

Answer (score 0):

Removing base64_encode() solved the problem.

Changed

```
$att->imagefile = base64_encode(file_get_contents($f->getRealPath()));
```

to

```
$att->imagefile = file_get_contents($f->getRealPath());
```